# Certificate verify error while using Anthropic client sdk

Tags: openai-api, large-language-model, anthropic, claude

I am trying to use the anthropic client sdk to call the API and get the below error.

> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self
> signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)

How can I overcome this?  Any workarounds.

Thanks